# How to draw these shapes using .Net drawing

Tags: .net, drawing

I want to draw the shapes on the link below:

http://www.sendspace.com/file/n1tx5t

Could anyone shed a light on this?

Please note the rounded corner of the shapes (polygon, arrow, etc. The colour of the shapes have to change dynamically), and it has to be used in web forms.

I tried transparent arrow with dynamic colour, but it did NOT work. Is it possible to draw a transparent image (*.png) on top of a Bitmap with background colour. Therefore, the colour of arrow will change?

Answer (score 1):

These shapes, aren't included by default in .NET, but assuming that you're either using WinForms or WPF you can easily show them by adding a picture box/ image control to your form and then selecting a picture of an arrow that you've created yourself/ or downloaded somewhere.

Here is a small tutorial about adding a picture box (for WinForms) http://www.startvbdotnet.com/controls/gbox.aspx )

And here is a small tutorial about the image control (for WPF) http://anuraj.wordpress.com/2008/05/17/displaying-image-in-wpf-image-control/

Comment: Thanks. Can picture box be used with Web Forms. Their colour have to change dynamically. Therefore, all elements including arrow have to generate dynamically. I tried transparent arrow with dynamic colour, but it did NOT work. Is it possible to draw a transparent image (*.png) on top of a Bitmap with background colour. Therefore, the colour of arrow will change?

Comment: Sorry I haven't used webforms much, but there has to be a picturebox-like control that you can use there.

Answer (score 1):

You can draw them using a paths in [GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/530a2kct.aspx) or in [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx)

Comment: Check out both links; they give examples & links to even more information.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tutorials I found that should get you started with rounded rectangles and gradient fills:

Gradient fills (ie. where the shading varies in color and/or density across the shape) are a standard feature:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229655.aspx

And this guide includes a class for rounded rectangles (.NET 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ExtendedGraphics.aspx

Although there are better ways of doing it in .NET 4:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.round.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Rounded polygon and arrow are required. Their colour have to change dynamically.